# Kotlin Android what is the Optimal way to store Bitmap Image in a data class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a very simple question..I am making a music player app and trying to store the music track thumbnails in the data class.

currently I am doing it like this

```
data class Track(
val uuid : UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
val track_id : Long = 233223,
val track_title : String?,
val track_length : Float,
val track_album : String?,
val track_bitmap: Bitmap?,
val track_artist : String?,
val info_format : String
)
```

so is `track_bitmap : Bitmap?` ?

keep in mind that I am a beginner, and also i am planning to implement room db to cache track list with their images and i am using jetpack compose.

so what is the optimal recommended way to store bitmap images in a situation like this. any advice is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Bitmaps can comsume a lot of memory, holding a reference to lots of bitmaps could increase memory pressure and would not scale well if user have 1000's of tracks (Android/Image libraries will do internal caching but thats out of scope).  Why not hold a reference to the thumbnail as a `Uri`and just load it when required - if its not on screen then there is not need to retain the image. This also mitigates against duplicate thumbnails stored as bitmaps as many tracks can use the same thumbnail.

Comment: many thanks for the comment..I will do as you suggested by storing the uri and loading it on request from the viewmodel.and if you wish you can answer the question and i will accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmaps can comsume a lot of memory, holding a reference to lots of bitmaps could increase memory pressure and would not scale well if user have 1000's of tracks (Android/Image libraries will do internal caching but thats out of scope).

Instead you could hold a reference to the thumbnail as a `Uri` or `long` image id and just load it when required - if its not on screen then there is not need to retain the image. This also mitigates against duplicate thumbnails stored as bitmaps as many tracks can use the same thumbnail.

You can then use :

For Api 29+ :

`val bitmap = contentResolver.loadThumbnail(track.thumbnailUri, Size(width, height), null)`

Or below Api 29 :

`val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(contentResolver, track.thumbNailId, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND, null)`

It is also common to just use a `Uri` and pass it off to a image loading library like Glide, Picasso or Coil.  If using a lot of images it I'd recommend using a library as it usually has a nice api surface that allows you to have custom placeholder images, asynchronous loading and transition animations which provides a much better user experience.